# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string

Tags: php, wordpress, function, typeerror

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in C:\OSPanel\domains\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\advanced-custom-fields-pro\includes\acf-value-functions.php:63 Stack trace: #0

code this function:

```
function acf_get_value( $field, $post_id = 0 ) {
    
    // Allow filter to short-circuit load_value logic.
    $value = apply_filters( "acf/pre_load_value", null, $post_id, $field );
    if( $value !== null ) {
        return $value;
    }
    // Get field name. 
    $field_name = $field['name']; // --- HERE ERROR ---
    
    // Check store.
    $store = acf_get_store( 'values' );
    if( $store->has( "$post_id:$field_name" ) ) {
        return $store->get( "$post_id:$field_name" );
    }
    
    // Load value from database.
    $value = acf_get_metadata( $post_id, $field_name );
    
    // Use field's default_value if no meta was found.
    if( $value === null && isset($field['default_value']) ) {
        $value = $field['default_value'];
    }
    
    /**
     * Filters the $value after it has been loaded.
     *
     * @date    28/09/13
     * @since   5.0.0
     *
     * @param   mixed $value The value to preview.
     * @param   string $post_id The post ID for this value.
     * @param   array $field The field array.
     */
    $value = apply_filters( "acf/load_value", $value, $post_id, $field );
    
    // Update store.
    $store->set( "$post_id:$field_name", $value );

    // Return value.
    return $value;
}
```

$field = get_field_object('name');
$field_name = $field['name'];

not working

Comment: I suggest doing a var_dump($field) just before the line causing the error.  What does it show?

Answer (score 1):

The error means you are trying to get a value from an associative array using a key that does not exist.

Based on the line you identified, change the code to:

```
// Get field name. 
$field_name = $field['name'] ?? '';
```

This is for php 7 and above.

If you are using a php version below 7, change the line to

```
$field_name = $field['name'] ?: '';
```

However, like the first comment suggested, do a var_dump($field) to see the contents of the array. The above code will only set a default value instead of giving a fatal error.